# Check if .ASPXAUTH exists?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, forms-authentication

Is there a way to see if this cookie exists? I can see the cookie in my browser's dev tools, but using JS and c# I am not able to do so. I do not actually need the data from it, I just want to see if it exists.

Comment: Why? You should just be able to check whether or not the user is authenticated via forms authentication?

Comment: What is the purpose of seeing if the cookie exists or not? IE, what is the business reasoning for checking it?

Comment: I want to know if a user has been logged out. NOT trying to check if a user is logged in.